# NSFetchRequest to-many key not allowed here

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have a many to many relationship between two entities; `A` and `B`.

I want to return an array of `B.relationship` for every `A` where `B.relationship`’s count is greater than 0 and sorted by `B`’s `dateCreated` property.

This is the code I currently have which probably makes a little more sense.

```
let fetchRecentVariationsRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Variation")
fetchRecentVariationsRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY activities.@count > 0")
fetchRecentVariationsRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "activities.dateCreated", ascending: true)]
```

When I run the request I get the following exception:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here’`

I understand why I’m getting the error but how I sort by a to many property for a sort descriptor in Core Data?

**Edit**

To be more clear, I’d like to fetch the 6 most recent `Activity` entities sorted by their `dateCreated` property (newest first).

Then I’d like to fetch all of the `Variation` entities which are related to these fetched `Activity` entities via the `Activity` entity’s `variations` relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  A couple of Qs: Suppose the first Activity has three Variations - what order should those be sorted in?  And if a Variation is related to the first Activity, and the fifth Activity, should it appear in the end results twice?

Comment: No problem. 1) Sorted by the `name` property on `Variation` entity. 2) That shouldn’t be possible in my model

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort by the attribute of a to-many relationship, because it makes no sense.  CoreData needs to decide which Variation to put first.  Your sort descriptor says "use the value of dateCreated on the related Activities".  But there are several Activities and so several different dateCreated values for each Variation.  Which Activities' dateCreated should it use?  The last?  The first?  The average?

But over and above that conceptual problem, CoreData will only allow you to use an attribute, or a to-one relationship, to sort by (at least for a fetch from the SQLite store).  No transient properties; no computed properties.  So if you want to use the dateCreated of the most recent related Activity, you will need to add an attribute to Variation which you update every time an Activity is added to the relationship.

**EDIT**

Given your update, I would fetch the most recent six Activities first:

```
fetchRecentActivitiesRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Activity")
fetchRecentActivitiesRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: false)]
fetchRecentActivitiesRequest.fetchLimit = 6
// I recommend using the next line to fetch the related Variations in one go
fetchRecentActivitiesRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["variations"]
let recentActivities = try! context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRecentActivitiesRequest) as! [Activity]
```

and then use the `variations` relationship to get the corresponding `Variations`:

```
let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
let recentVariations = recentActivities.flatMap() {
    $0.variations!.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([nameSort])
}
```

Comment: So what kind of `NSfetchRequest` should I be using?

Comment: @AdamCarter Can you edit your post to explain in greater detail how you would like things sorted - perhaps with some examples?

Comment: Just updated my question to be a little more clear :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I’ll let you know if there’s any issue but it seems like it should work. :)